# Weird error C2131 with constexpr declared variable

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to compile the following snippet with VS2017 but it is throwing an `error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant` without any further detail in the output log.

```
class Example
{
public:
    constexpr Example() : m_int()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 256; ++j)
            {
                m_int[i] = i;
            }
        }
    }

private:
    int m_int[256];
};

int main()
{
    constexpr Example vv; // <-- error C2131 here
    return 0;
}
```

However for some reason unknown to me, if I stop the j counter at `< 255` (instead of 256), the code compile fine.
What's the explanation behind this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Don't see anything obviously wrong, so this looks like a compiler bug. gcc compiles the above without any issues.

Comment: Compiles fine with [MSVC](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6DdSmD)

Comment: I have just found the solution, I'll post the answer right away, thanks!

Comment: What does the inner loop even do?  It’s just assigning to the same element over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

Further searching landed me on the following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/constexpr-control-constexpr-evaluation?view=vs-2019) and after some trial and error with the parameters values I found the solution.

Adding `/constexpr:steps10000000` to the project additional options in C++ compiler settings has fixed the error and now it compiles fine. I wish VS2017 would throw the error C4593 in this case instead of C2131 as it would have saved me a headache!